# How can I use mvc Html.RadioButtonFor in same Action. ( Nopcommerce payment info)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, html.radiobuttonlist

I have one action result [HttpGet]. I want show data with radio buttons and get which is selected same action [HttpGet]. Someone give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Views\Catalog\ProductReviews.cshtm view, where @Html.RadioButtonFor is used to select rating value, and the appropriate ProductReviewsAdd method in the CatalogController